# Angular detect route change only when navigating to a different component

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am trying to do something upon route change (i.e scroll to top) only when navigating to a different component in my application but not when staying on the same component and just changing its view by a route to the same component with different query params

For example, If I am at `/products?category=kitchen` and I navigate to `/products?category=bedroom` I don't want the the operation (i.e scroll to top) to perform.

This is the code in my app.component.ts:

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
  // Would like to check here if user navigates to different component
  if (window) window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

Does anybody know how I can achieve that?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @MuhammadMabrouk Yes, i've just posted the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I want to share how I solved this just in case someone will encounter somthing similar in the future:

```js
private componentBeforeNavigation = null;
  private setScrollToTopOnNavigation() {
    // Scroll to top only when navigating to a different component
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
      let currentRoute = this.route;
      while (currentRoute.firstChild) currentRoute = currentRoute.firstChild;
      if (this.componentBeforeNavigation !== currentRoute.component) {
        if (window) window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
      this.componentBeforeNavigation = currentRoute.component;
    });
  }
```

What this code is doing is using a private property for the component called `componentBeforeNavigation` which is initially `null` and every time the Navigation event is fired, the code in the `subscribe` check if the place I'm navigating now is the same as the last navigation. If yes, it means it is a navigation to the same component and I don't perform my special action (in this case scroll to top of the window) and if no, it means it is a navigation to a new component.
One important thing is to store the new component that I'm navigating to in the property `componentBeforeNavigation` so it is always updated with the last navigation

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks again for your help 

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the `ActivatedRoute` paramMap to do your stuff:

```
this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe(paramMap  =>  {
        this.router.navigate('your child route here');
    });
```

and make sure the category view is a child route of `products`.

Also in place of *products view in html template* add a routing placeholder where the child view will be placed:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

You can read more about nested [routing here:](https://medium.com/@shairez/angular-routing-a-better-pattern-for-large-scale-apps-f2890c952a18)

Comment: Thank you for the suggested answer but the problem with it is that this will allow me to run code only when I route to the same component while I wanted the code to run on every route change except when routing to the same component. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @yanivps did you resolve the issue, I also have the same

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Since I don't know your usecase, I can only assume that you are trying to achieve the following:

In your application, somehow, the query parameter "category" can be changed, e.g. through a click on a category. Instead of doing a

`router.navigate(['/products?category=' + newlySelectedCategory]);`

and probably reacting on that query parameter with

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  category: string;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Note: Below 'queryParams' can be replaced with 'params' depending on your requirements
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.category = params['category'];
    });
  }

}
```

you can do:

```
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';
import {OnInit, Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  category: string;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Note: Below 'queryParams' can be replaced with 'params' depending on your requirements
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.category = params['category'];
    });
  }

  // This will probably be called from your html code
  selectCategory(category: string) {
     this.category = category;
     this.location.replaceState(`products?category=${category}`);
  }
}
```

This way, there will be no routing.

---

One possible way is to not route, but to change the current URL with `this.location.replaceState` (assuming you injected `private location: Location` in your constructor) and manually start the same process that would happen, when you read out the query parameter of the url.

Comment: Not quite sure I understood you. Can you edit and provide any pseudo example? Thanks

Comment: I have replaced the state, but my router.url and activatedroute is not detecting the state change

Comment: A state change differs from a route change. The state is merely a displayname. To notify router.url and activatedRoute you have to do a router.navigate to that location.